# Flutter[firebase_storage] Unable to upload images on iOS 14+ using Flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

**Bug report**
Describe the bug
When uploading a file using UploadTask task = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('Your reference').putFile(File file) on iOS 14 I get the message "**BackgroundSession <7D713C0B-93C0-4B46-952E-7519FB15A8BF> connection to background transfer daemon invalidated"**, resulting in the Future hanging and never uploading the file. Adding a listener on the UploadTask also does not seem to provide any output. Awaiting for the UploadTask to finish just hangs without ever resolving or throwing an error.

This seems to be a problem on an IOS phone (iphone X version 14+), because it works perfectly on Android and on the IOS emulator

**Steps to reproduce**
On an iOS 14+ device, try uploading a File to Firebase Storage using UploadTask task = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('Your reference').putFile(File file) successfully.

**Steps to reproduce the behavior:**

Try uploading a File to Firebase Storage using UploadTask task = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('Your reference').putFile(File file)
Await for the UploadTask to finish -> await task
See debug console for **"BackgroundSession <7D713C0B-93C0-4B46-952E-7519FB15A8BF> connection to background transfer daemon invalidated" message**
Wait forever for the UploadTask to never finish
Expected behavior
The UploadTask should either complete, or throw an error